# Hammock Package , Tweetsharp and C# Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp, hammock

I followed this link

http://samjarawan.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/building-real-windows-phone-7-twitter_18.html

step by step and when I am running my app, I am getting an error i.e. "Error Calling Twitter".

When I searched about it, I found that in this part of code

```
 var client = new RestClient
            {
                Authority = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth",
                Credentials = credentials,
                HasElevatedPermissions = true,
                SilverlightAcceptEncodingHeader = "gzip",
                DecompressionMethods = DecompressionMethods.GZip

            };
```

I need to do some changes, but what changes didn't find any where. Another answer I got that I need to update Hammock and Tweetsharp, but its already updated. Please suggest me and help me out.

Comment: What message are you receiving from Twitter? Where is the code failing?

Comment: I am getting "Error Calling Twitter" message ..

Answer (score -1):

Try changing DecompressionMethods or SilverlightAcceptEncodingHeader.